# Button Background Image changing size

Tags: c#

I have a button with a background image, the problem is that when I'm in the design form and I set a background image to the icon I must make the icon larger than the image then when I compile it the image has the size of the icon. I can't explain properly so I'm sending an image which show my program before and after compilation. I'm doing something wrong or it is normal?

http://imageshack.com/a/img138/5980/5cng.png

Comment: How anout [Control.BackgroundImageLayout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: What kind of button is this? Windows Forms?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yes it is Windows Forms